# How to use older version assembly in GAC when newer versions are also available?

Tags: .net

I have an assembly with multiple versions, all have been deployed in GAC.
Now by default the latest version assembly is used by the program which uses it, how do i use any previous versions?

Comment: "by default the latest version assembly is used" - what uses latest version of assembly (your program, some tool, VS when adds references)?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov , have edited question based on your comment.

Comment: are you referring to a COM Registered assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [assembly publisher policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz32563a.aspx) in order to do that.

> Now by default the latest version assembly is used by the program
>   which uses it

Are you sure about that ?  Isn't it so that the version that was referenced by your program during compile-time, is being used ?